# How to make dynamic rowspan php codeigniter?

Tags: php, html, codeigniter

I have table `rowspan` dynamic on CodeIgniter app like this :

```
<table>
<tr>
    <td>No</td>
    <td>Data</td>
    <td>Data 2</td>
    <td>Qty</td>
    <td>Price</td>
    <td>Sub Total</td>
    <td>TOtal</td>
</tr>
<?php

$source1 = $this->db->query("select * from table")->result_array(); 
$no=1;
foreach($source1 as source1){ ?>
    <tr>
        <?php 
        $source2 = $this->db->query("select * from table where data1='$source1[data1]'");
        $total_source2 = $source2->num_rows();
        $source3 = $source2->result_array();
        ?>
        <td rowspan="<?php echo $total_source2 ?>"><?php echo $no; ?></td>
        <td rowspan="<?php echo $total_source2 ?>"><?php echo $source1['data1']; ?></td>
        <?php foreach($source3 as $source3){ ?>
            <td><?php echo $source3['data2'] ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $source3['qty'] ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $source3['price'] ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $source3['sub_total'] ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $source3['total'] ?></td>
        </tr>
    <?php } ?>
    <?php $no++; } ?>
</table>
```

This is result of my code:

[image: table 1]

How to make it like this

[image: table 2]

?

Thanks.

Comment: Can you upload an export for the sql file for the table? Just put it on a free file upload service and post here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is about as efficient as anything I can come up with without the actual SQL file and I'm not sure if it works:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>No</td>
        <td>Data</td>
        <td>Data 2</td>
        <td>Qty</td>
        <td>Price</td>
        <td>Sub Total</td>
        <td>Total</td>
    </tr>
    <?php
    $source1 = $this->db->query("select * from table")->result_array();
    $no = 1;
    foreach ($source1 as $source1) {
        ?>
        <tr>
            <?php
            $source2 = $this->db->query('select * from table where data1 = ' . $source1['data1']);
            $total_source2 = $source2->num_rows();
            $source3 = $source2->result_array();
            $rowspan = true;
            ?>
            <td rowspan="<?php echo $total_source2 ?>"><?php echo $no; ?></td>
            <td rowspan="<?php echo $total_source2 ?>"><?php echo $source1['data1']; ?></td>
            <?php foreach ($source3 as $source3) { ?>
                <td><?php echo $source3['data2'] ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $source3['qty'] ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $source3['price'] ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $source3['sub_total'] ?></td>
                <?php
                if ($rowspan) {
                    $q = $this->db->query('SELECT SUM(`sub_total`) as `nb` FROM `table` WHERE `data1` = ' . $source1['data1']);
                    echo "<td rowspan='{$total_source2}'>" . $q->row()->nb . '</td>';
                    $rowspan = false;
                }
                ?>
            </tr>
        <?php } ?>
        <?php
        $no++;
    }
    ?>
</table>
```

Comment: Thank very much. :)